# how to use "recursiveFileLookup=true" without cancelling the "spark partition reading" benefit from the basePath option in Azure databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

We are trying to make a general purpose ingesting framework. We want to be able to read different folders in our system.

We have noticed two kinds of partitionned folder in our system:

- spark partitionning : `mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220102/`
- multi depth partitionning : `mnt/sales/2022/05/07/`

**using basePath :**
We are using the mode `.option("basePath", '/mnt/sales/').load('mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220102/')`
The basePath option here allows non delta files to be read **using the schema of the specific file** inside the partition, **while allowing the partionned column to still be available in the dataset**. We do that because we want to be able to check whether a newly received csv has a wrong schema, just for today's partition.

Our problem is that sometimes we want to load `mnt/sales/2022/05/` instead of eg. `mnt/sales/2022/05/07.`

==> we get the error due to the fact the spark does not read sublevel folders.

> 'unable to infer schema for csv'

To solve this, we are reading a **list of files** instead of a **path**, which is making this method **unusable** for **delta tables**.

We also see that this could potentially be solved by using `.option("recursiveFileLookup","true")` but this cancels the effect of `basePath` option.

Is there a way we can use both recursiveFileLookup and benefit from the basePath option ?

Answer (score 0):

- The requirement can be achieved without the help of `recursiveFileLookup` using wildcard file paths.
- The wildcard file path successfully solves the problem that you are facing i.e., reading both `mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220102/` and `mnt/sales/2022/05/` (instead of 'mnt/sales/2022/05/07' as you mentioned) .
- One problem would be when a certain directory is a delta file folder as it would not accept wildcards. So, check whether the directory you want to read is a **Delta table or not**. If the directory path is not a delta table, then you can use wildcard with the path else, you can read the delta directly.
- The following is a demonstration of the same where I have taken different paths and tried to read them only using `basePath` option.

```
from delta import * 
from delta.tables import DeltaTable 

#my paths
paths = ['/mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220102/','/mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220103/','/mnt/sales/2022/05/']

for path in paths:
    if(DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, path)):
        print("delta table")
        mydf =spark.read.option("header",True).option("basePath","/mnt/sales/").format("delta").load(path)
    else:
        print("not a delta table:")
        path = path+'*'   #since the directory is not delta file folder, add a wildcard path.
        mydf = spark.read.option("header",True).option("basePath","/mnt/sales/").format("csv").load(path)
    mydf.show()
```

[image]

- The above code solves your requirement without the need of `recursiveFileLookup`.

**NOTE:**

- If `07` is a delta file folder in the path `mnt/sales/2022/05/07` and you only want to read `mnt/sales/2022/05`, it won't be possible. You have to specify the exact delta file folder path to be able to read delta.
- Adding wildcards to a delta file folder (or) a parent of delta folder throws an error, therefore we used the condition on the available path to check if it is a delta or not. The following is a reference image of the same.

[image]

This way, you can just use `basePath` option to read from either delta or path like `/mnt/sales/ingestdate=20220102/` or path like `/mnt/sales/2022/05/` (instead of '/mnt/sales/2022/05/07').